Does `static` have any effect if compiling in a single translation unit?
Suppose I write a huge, self-contained C file and compile it like cc -O3 main.c. What will be the differences if I had declared every function other than main() and every variable in the file static or not? Will it have an effect on optimisation?

What kind of "effect on optimisation" are you envisioning?

Why wouldn't you want declare every function apart from main static? What purpose an extern function would serve?

@n.m.couldbeanAI I am asking if explicitly writing the word static before every function would actually have any effect, given that the file in question is self-contained.

I am asking why you would ever consider not writing static before every function that can be static?

Aside: why are you writing a program as one huge file, rather than decomposing the problem into separate compilation units?

@Chris, I learnt about unity builds in C, where the C files themselves are #included into the main file (it can apparently lead to more optimisations being performed) and was refactoring a project into this style to try it out and was wondering if I still needed the static keyword in that case.

Static definitely makes a difference with variables.

@n.m.couldbeanAI, I was wondering if it is "implied" in this case as we're just compiling main directly. The same way that I don't need to write = 0 for the first enum value because the spec already implies it. Sorry, perhaps I have not phrased or explained my question very well.

Re “What will be the differences if I had declared every function and variable in the file static or not?”: If you declare every function static, the linker will not be able to link the program since it will not be able to resolve the essential reference to main in the startup code.

With modern compilers, enabling link time optimization is probably better than a giant amalgamation/unity build.

@n.m.couldbeanAI Perhaps the simple fact that almost every single example program on the Internet (not to mention K&R) does not declare every function static that can be so declared. The OP appears to be questioning that common convention, suspecting that including static could allow the optimizer to do a better job. (FYI to OP: I've seen conflicting evidence in my own experience.)

If you declare a local variable as static, a recursive call to the function will not have its own instance of the variable. It may also affect optimization, since the lifetime is different.

No, static is not implied, extern is.

Thank you Shawn and Streve Ford for giving useful answers to the question that I was (to me) clearly asking.

@You'reNotARobot be careful with Shawn's first response, that static makes a difference with variables. I think he might have been alluding to the same point Weather Vane brought up that setting a function's local variable to static changes its semantics, both related to recursion and multithreading. Don't set local variables to static without good reason.

Yes static will have an effect on function inlining. If a function is local to the current translation unit, the compiler can make the decision to inline it. Otherwise inlining might only happen if done through link-time optimizations.

static variables at file scope may also get optimized better because the compiler will know that parameters passed to functions through pointers are not an alias for the file scope variable. Example:
static int x;

static void func (int* a, int* b)
{
  *a = x + *b;
}

int main()
{
  func(&some_var, &some_other_var);
}


Here the compiler can easily tell that x isn't modified by the function and that neither of the parameters a or b are pointing to x. Which wouldn't necessarily be possible to assume if neither the variable nor the function were static. Because then if the function were called from another translation unit, the caller might be accessing x and passing it along to func.

static variables at local scope may however reduce performance a tiny bit, because such variables must be initialized before main() is called. Example:
void func (void)
{
  static int x;
  x = a + b;
}

Here the compiler must first generate code that initializes x to zero before main() is called, and then again generate code that overwrites that zero value when the function is called. static also generally prevents variables from getting stored in CPU registers.
